# How to merge two V0 `VersionedTransaction` in Rust?

Tags: transactions

How to merge two `VersionedTransaction` (V0 transaction format) into one Transaction in Rust?

https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/transaction/struct.VersionedTransaction.html

Comment: Share the part of code where you want to merge it.

Answer (score 1):

Merging versioned transactions essentially involves extracting all instructions and account keys from both transactions and then combining them by creating a new one.